# Python Wheel (pip install) with Git hooks

Tags: python, git, pip, githooks

I'm trying to move some git hooks into place as part of a pip install target command, but pip seems to refuse and if I use upgrade, it blows away the git folder. I think [this Github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4230) is the problem, but just trying to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's an issue with using a folder that starts with a "." so I just target in the command to ".git" and had the setup.py move the hooks into "hooks" (instead of a target of "." and the setup.py using ".git/hooks").